# Trying to change the name of the downloaded CSV based on a form field id value

Tags: javascript

`I'm setting up a Form2CSV JavaScript. The form works and I can download the form as csv to the local download folder. The downloaded csv file is named generic/ automatically "download.csv" and I would like to change the name of the csv, so that it gets downloaded and named with one for the form field data, example: txtPOC1. How can I do this?

```
<form action="/action_page.php" method="post" required autocomplete="off"\>


<td style="width: 300px"\>\<input id="txtPOC1" type="text" rows="1" size="55" name="fPOC1"\>\</td\>

<input type="button" id="addButton" class = "no-printme" value="Save to Download Folder" onClick="javascript: addToCSVFile()" /\>

<script type="text/javascript"\>
function addToCSVFile() {
var csvData = new Array();  // To collect the names

// Collecting the names
csvData[0] = document.getElementById('txtPOC1').value;
window.open('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + csvData.join(','));
    
clearData();
alert("Saved to Download Folder");
}
    
function clearData() {
document.getElementById('txtPOC1').value = "";
</script>
```